Google Annotation chart Invalid date, or date and time error
I am having problem in formatting the date column for Google Annotation chart. I am following this link https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/annotationchart
My Data for Annotation chart
 var init_data = [["Week","A","A Title","A Annot","B","B Title","B Annot"],
["2022-05-01T18:30:00.000Z",10,"A","AAA",1984,"B","BBB"],
["2022-05-08T18:30:00.000Z",36,"A","AAA",150,"B","BBB"],
["2022-05-15T18:30:00.000Z",30,"A","AAA",199,"B","BBB"],
["2022-05-22T18:30:00.000Z",33,"A","AAA",184,"B","BBB"],
["2022-05-29T18:30:00.000Z",20,"A","AAA",161,"B","BBB"],
["2022-06-05T18:30:00.000Z",37,"A","AAA",172,"B","BBB"],
["2022-06-12T18:30:00.000Z",22,"A","AAA",151,"B","BBB"]]

I using below function to convert to mm/dd/yyyy format
function convertdate(date) {
        date = new Date(date);
        //console.log(date);
        let year = date.getFullYear();
        let month = (1 + date.getMonth()).toString().padStart(2, '0');
        let day = date.getDate().toString().padStart(2, '0');         
        return month + '/' + day + '/' + year;
        }

Applying above function my data look like

var data = [['Week','A','A Title','A Annot','B','B Title','B Annot'],
['05/01/2022',10,'A','AAA',1984,'B','BBB'],
['05/08/2022',36,'A','AAA',150,'B','BBB'],
['05/15/2022',30,'A','AAA',199,'B','BBB'],
['05/22/2022',33,'A','AAA',184,'B','BBB'],
['05/29/2022',20,'A','AAA',161,'B','BBB'],
['06/05/2022',37,'A','AAA',172,'B','BBB'],
['06/12/2022',22,'A','AAA',151,'B','BBB']]

And I am passing above data to Array to DataTable function
var chart_data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(data);
          var chart = new google.visualization.AnnotationChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));

          var options = {
            displayAnnotations: true
          };

          chart.draw(chart_data, options);

It throws error in the browser(Google)

First column must contain date, or date and time.

I tried uing new Date() it gives me the date format like
Mon Oct 09 2023 00:00:00 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time) // This throws same error as well

How to format the date column for Google Annotation chart.

Given the supplied link, the first member of each data array is a Date object, not a string. The conversion to M/D/Y timestamp seems redundant and problematic. Just convert original timestamps to Date using new Date(timestamp).

I did that but the same error. I fixed it by using ChartWrapper function passing data to chart as a DataTable

Below solution worked for me by using Chart Wrapper function and RegEx function to convert string to date.
Create an DataTable, push output array to dataTable.
var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
data.addColumn('date', 'Week');
data.addColumn('number', 'A');
data.addColumn('string', 'A Title');
data.addColumn('string', 'A Annot');
data.addColumn('number', 'B');
data.addColumn('string', 'B Title');
data.addColumn('string', 'B Annot');

for (var i = 0; i < json_arr.length; i++){
     var dt_ = new Date(json_arr[i][0].replace(/(\d{2})-(\d{2})-(\d{4})/,"$2/$1/$3"));            
     data.addRow([dt_,json_arr[i][1],json_arr[i][2],json_arr[i][3],json_arr[i] 
         [4],json_arr[i][5],json_arr[i][6]]);
}

var annot_chart = new google.visualization.ChartWrapper({
            chartType: 'AnnotationChart',
            containerId: 'chart_div',
            dataTable: data,
            options: {
              displayAnnotations: true           
            }         
          });         

          annot_chart.draw(); 


The date format in your question (e.g. "2022-05-01T18:30:00.000Z") doesn't match the regular expression in your answer (/(\d{2})-(\d{2})-(\d{4})/). Also, new Date("2022-05-01T18:30:00.000Z") is almost certain to work in all current browsers going back maybe 10 years. Something is happening that you're not telling us. Also, this method shifts the date by the host's timezone offset, whatever that might be.
